# Do flechette rounds pierce/reduce armor?

Tags: payday-2

Do flechette rounds actually bypass shields and/or reduce the effectiveness of armor?  If yes, does the damage drop to 25% similar to how AP rounds work with shields?  I haven't had much luck using these effectively in game.

I was hoping to find an answer in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167570/how-does-shooting-through-multiple-targets-work-with-the-update-27-and-31-gage), but the answers were not updated for shotgun ammo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flechette rounds do not penetrate Shield units' shield. They can only penetrate armor (e.g. tan cop body armor). Penetration of armors do not reduce the damage (unlike how AP slug rounds work with shields).